# | operator operation in linq?

Tags: linq

|(pipe) operator in linq?i want to know operation of operator(|).i want to check multiple columns in different table.In my scenario only single table contain value for that perticular column.

my code:

```
&& swr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date | 
   spr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date | 
   scr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date | 
   smr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date
```

In this scenario only one table will contain date value others will contain dault values in their respected columns.

The above condition is not working,it takes default value.

what condition can i use to get correct value?

Answer (score 2):

The `|` operator gives the same result as the `||` operator, but it's not short-circuiting the result. That means that both operands are always evaluated even if the result can be determined by evaluating only the first operand.

I think that the main problem is that the `&&` operator has higher precedence than the `|` operator (or the `||` operator), so you need parentheses:

```
&& (swr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date | 
    spr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date | 
    scr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date | 
    smr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date)
```

You can use the short-circuiting version of the operator instead, as reading the `Date` properties doesn't have any side effects:

```
&& (swr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date ||
    spr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date ||
    scr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date ||
    smr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to use `||` instead? they look like "or" constraints to me... also, when mixing `&&` and `||`, be **very** clear with brackets... i.e. is it `(x && y) || z`, or `x && (y || z)`

Comment: They *are* "or" contraints, the `|` operator gives the same result as the `||` operator.

Comment: @Guffa in this case, yes, but in the general case that isn't guaranteed - for example `true | ThrowsAnException()` gives a different result to `true || ThrowsAnException()`. My point simply: it looks like the OP should be using `||` here, as the most idiomatic way of expressing their intent.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to replace | with || and you probably want to put those four condition in parenthesis after the && operator. Like this:

```
&& (swr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date || 
    spr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date || 
    scr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date || 
    smr.Date_Of_Event.Date < DateTime.Today.Date)
```